# Multisite with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, base-url

I'm new to this (wonderful) website!
I did search for an answear to my problem but I could not find it.
(Q: bad english. A: I'm italian, sorry.)

**My goal:**


I would host in a domain 2 different websites, each of them using their proper htaccess rules.


**The structure:**

```
/index.html --> empty page.

/site1/index.html
/site1/styleA.css
/site1/logo.png

/site2/index.html
/site2/styleB.css
/site2/logo.png
```

**The problem:**


/site1/index.html gets the stylesheet file using absolute path:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css" />
```

this way it try to get the "style.css" file in the root directory (404).

Same problem with site2 and every other file that use absolute path.


**More info:**

- Sites are stored in folders only to test them, they will be moved to different domains once ready so I would not edit every absolute path.
- I'm not using Wordpress, Drupal or similar. They're all my creations.

**The Question:**


Is it possible to solve the 'absolute path' problems using only .htaccess file(s)?
If not, what would you suggest me to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you can check the referer:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} /site1/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/site1/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /site1/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} /site2/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/site2/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /site2/$1 [L]
```

This doesn't redirect the browser, so there's a possibility that the browser will cache a "/style.css" and the two sites get mixed, so you may want to redirect the browser instead by changing the flags from `[L]` to `[L,R]`.

Comment: I think I love you. "two sites get mixed" --> can't solve with `[L,R]`, `Ctrl+F5` do.